# Fairtrade open dataset, UK

Tags: data-request, uk

Is there an open or freely available dataset on fairtrade goods (produce and products) in the UK? Looking for product, produce type, price data, location data but would be interested in any dataset regarding fairtrade goods. UK would be ideal, EU would also be good.

Answer (score 3):

The UK Department for Environment, Food and Rural Affairs publishes a weekly price index for commodities:

https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/commodity-prices

And here is the weekly dataset for weekly wholesale prices for vegetables and fruits:

https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/wholesale-fruit-and-vegetable-prices

The European Commission keeps data related to cost of goods vs. cost of labor for countries in the EU in the EuroStat database.

http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/statistics/themes

The National Accounts (with GDP) will provides indexes on current prices relative to GDP.

http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/product_details/dataset?p_product_code=NAMA_GDP_C

The Agriculture section contains data related to farm labor costs, income, price and production.

http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/agriculture/data/database

Beow is a link of the [historical] annual difference of price of consumables and builder's wages in England from mid 1200s and 1885. It is an aggregation from a number of compiled acacdemic sources. The chart shows that as government (and corresponding taxes) evolved in the development of England that the gap increases each year.

http://esfdb.websites.bta.com/table.aspx?resourceid=11484